# InputBox data validation and end loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code to enter dates via `InputBox` (see below). The problem is that the `Else` doesn't work (ie. if the user enters something other than the format mm/dd/yy it doesn't stop). How do I make it so that the user has to enter it in the format presented?

Also, I want to end the loop with the `endDate`. Right now, if you enter 01/10/20 as the start date and 12/31/20 as the end date, it will stop at January 1, 2021. How do I make it stop at December 31, 2020?

````
  Dim startDate As Date
  Dim endDate As Date

  startDate = InputBox("Enter project start date in format mm/dd/yy", "User date", Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy"))
  endDate = InputBox("Enter project end date in format mm/dd/yy", "User date", Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy"))

  If IsDate(startDate) Then
    startDate = Format(CDate(startDate), "mmm d, yyyy")
  Else
    MsgBox "Wrong date format"
  End If

  If IsDate(endDate) Then
    endDate = Format(CDate(endDate), "mmm d, yyyy")
  Else
    MsgBox "Wrong date format"
  End If

Range("A2").Value = startDate

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim x As Integer

i = startDate
j = endDate
x = 3

Do Until i >= j
    Cells(x, 1).Value = i + 7
    i = i + 7
    x = x + 1
Loop

End Sub```
````

Comment: I'm guessing `Else` isn't working since `If IsDate(startDate)` is only checking if it's a valid date, not the format. And if it's not a date, I'm guessing the code will crash on the inputbox. Also I tried that last loop with the mentioned dates, and it does seem to stop at `12/31/20` for me. But since you skip 7 days each time, it's easy to see that you could easily miss your target date.

Comment: In addition to what @ChristoferWeber commented, I'll add that if you want it to stop after an invalid date is entered, you need to capture your input as a String and then after the MsgBox add Exit Sub.

Answer (score 0):

When the date is incorrect it is displaying the message box but there is nothing to stop it from continuing through the code after the message box is closed. There are several ways you can fix this.

The first is to simply add the line

```
Exit Sub
```

after the msgbox is displayed.

However, I'm assuming you don't want the program to just give up after an incorrect input. Instead you likely want it to inform the user it was incorrect and ask for another input until they provide a valid format.

The way I typically do this is with a Do Until loop. Try this:

```
  startDate = InputBox("Enter project start date in format mm/dd/yy", "User date", 
  Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy"))

  Do Until IsDate(startDate)
    MsgBox "Wrong date format."
    startDate = InputBox("Enter project start date in format mm/dd/yy", "User date", 
  Loop

  endDate = InputBox("Enter project end date in format mm/dd/yy", "User date", 
  Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy"))

  Do Until IsDate(endDate)
    MsgBox "Wrong date format."
    startDate = InputBox("Enter project start date in format mm/dd/yy", "User date", 
  Loop
```

The second problem is because you are checking i's value *before* you add 7 to it. Plus, the endDate only gets printed if it happens to be a multiple of 7 away from the startDate. If you always want the end date to print you'll have to make some changes.

Try this instead:

```
i = startDate + 7
j = endDate
x = 3

Do Until i > j
    Cells(x, 1).Value = i
    i = i + 7
    x = x + 1
Loop

Cells(x, 1).Value = endDate
```